Getting Object does not exist at location. Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404 Error trying to add an image to Firebase Storage
I'm using Android Studio with Java to make an android app, I'm trying to let the user pick an image from their gallery then upload that to firebase but I keep getting this error. I've already configured by rules properly from the console. I suspect it may have to do with permissions, I've put ACCES_NETWORK_STATE in my manifest but still getting this error. I've used the Android Studio debugger and both the reference and URI are defined and seem to look as expected.
This is the relevant code from the activity that I'm trying to upload from

private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> resultLauncher;
private ActivityResultLauncher<PickVisualMediaRequest> pickMedia;
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    imageUri = null;
    ...
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    storageReference = storage.getReference(Listing.LISTING_PATH);
    //The picker for photos
    pickMedia = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia(), uri -> {
        // Callback is invoked after the user selects a media item or closes the
        // photo picker.
        if (uri != null) {
            imageUri = uri;
            if(imageView!= null) imageView.setImageURI(uri);
        } else {
            Log.d("PhotoPicker", "No media selected");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No media selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
...
}
//Method that shows a dialog which the user picks an image from
private void showAddListingDialog() {
    ...

    final Button chooseImage = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.chooseImageButton);
    imageView = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    ...
    final AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();

    chooseImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            pickMedia.launch(new PickVisualMediaRequest.Builder()
                    .setMediaType(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly.INSTANCE)
                    .build());
        }
    });

    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ...
                if(imageUri != null) uploadPicture();
                dialog.dismiss();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ListingActivity.this, "Please fill out all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

//Method that adds picture to storage
private void uploadPicture(){
    StorageReference pictureReference = storageReference.child(category.getId()+".jpg");

    pictureReference.putFile(imageUri).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
            Toast.makeText(ListingActivity.this, "Could not store image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());

        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, etc.
            Toast.makeText(ListingActivity.this, "Successfully stored image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

My manifest permission
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

What does category.getId() return?

category.getId() returns a String, I'm using Firebase realtime database to store Category objects, it returns its id in the database

So you are sure that imageUri contains the correct data?

Yeah I think so, when I open the debugger all the info is there, I can see what the uriString is for example. And I'm setting the uri to an ImageView which shows the correct image. I am using Android Studio's picker to get it though, maybe it's some security feature they added?
